# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined - When echon an array into script

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I try to pass an array into script. The script work good and sent the desired data. The problem is , an error :

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined**

```
<!-- Send the Item data for each item in the shopping cart -->

<script>    
    var orderId = <?php echo $orders['orders_id'];?>;
    var products_array = <?php echo json_encode($products_array);?>;

  skroutz_analytics('ecommerce', 'addItem', JSON.stringify({

    order_id:   orderId ,                         // Order ID. Required.
    product_id: products_array[0]['id'],          // Product ID. Required.                           
    name:       products_array[0]['text'],        // Product Name. Required.
    price:      products_array[0]['price'],       // Price per Unit. Required.                                 
    quantity:   products_array[0]['quantity'],    // Quantity of Items. Required.

  }));
</script>
```

The declare of product array:

```
$products_array = array();
$products_query = tep_db_query("select products_id, products_name, products_price, products_quantity, products_tax from " . 
TABLE_ORDERS_PRODUCTS . " where orders_id = '" . 
(int)$orders['orders_id'] . "' order by products_name");

while ($products = tep_db_fetch_array($products_query)) {
       $products_array[] = array('id' => $products['products_id'],
                            'text' => $products['products_name'],
                            'price' => $products['products_price'],
                            'quantity' => $products['products_quantity']);                                                  
}
```

Comment: Show us `$products_array` ?

Comment: `products_array[0]` is undefined.  Check the length of products_array

Comment: Hi there, I put the declaration to the post.

Answer (score 0):

[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.json-encode.php) return an object, not array, so probably u should use `products_array->0->id`, also **Cannot read property** is a common error, you should learn how to debug these common errors, in this case you can check what is `products_array` with `console.log(products_array)` or in php to check what is `$products_array` with `var_dump($products_array)`

Comment: Or a simple glance at the browser js debugger should be enough

Answer (score 0):

Problem in the `$products array` $products array length, it length not greater than 1 or it has not "0" index.

Can you check it following code:

```
<script>    

    var orderId = <?php echo $orders['orders_id'];?>;
    var products_array = <?php echo json_encode([$products_array]);?>;



  skroutz_analytics('ecommerce', 'addItem', JSON.stringify({

    order_id:   orderId ,                                    // Order ID. Required.
    product_id: products_array[0]['id'],                                    // Product ID. Required.
    name:       products_array[0]['text'],  // Product Name. Required.
    price:      products_array[0]['price'],                                    // Price per Unit. Required.
    quantity:   products_array[0]['quantity'],// Quantity of Items. Required.

    }));
</script>
```

I added `$products_array` variable  into an array

Comment: Can you see output of the $products_array?

Comment: when I send the order , the page crashes

Comment: I don't understand. 

You can print products_array via console.log(products_array) and copy output from browser console tab.

Comment: products_array
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {id: "1563", text: "ΒΑΣΗ ΠΟΔΗΛΑΤΟΥ ΚΟΤΣΑΔΟΡΟΥ  EUROWAY 923(3 ΠΟΔΗΛΑΤΑ)", price: "539.0000", quantity: "1"}
1: {id: "1647", text: "ΦΩΤΑ ΞΕΝΟΝ Η4, ΒΙ ΧΕΝΟΝ 6000K", price: "35.0000", quantity: "1"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)

Answer (score 0):

json_encode($products_array) will return object.
If you change this to 
json_encode($products_array, true); it will return an array

Comment: thank you my friend, I try it but the same error exists.. 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined'

Comment: Pleas view page source and provide the output generated by php from the line var products_array = <?php echo json_encode([$products_array]);?>;

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It's work with your solution!!! Maybe the catch of the server didn't show me the (no errors)